# How to prevent the methods of a base class?

Tags: c#

How to prevent the access of  method1 for sub2 class and method2 for sub1 class ?

```
public class Main
{

    void Method1()       //prevent this method for sub2
    {
    }
    void Method2()//prevent this method for sub1
    {
    }
}

public class sub1: Main
{

}

public class sub2: Main
{

}
```

Comment: make them `private` which is the default

Comment: If you want them to only be accessible in one of the two subclasses, you put the method in that class instead of in the baseclass.

Comment: You can't hide a method like you are suggesting here. instead introduce a "middle-base-class" that has either one of the methods.

Comment: @DanielA.White OP want only one of the two methods to be accessible for two different classes.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. That is: you have some problem, you have a wrong idea about how to solve it, and you're asking about that wrong idea.  What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve?  Say what that is and we can try to help you solve the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

What you can do is either add another layer of classes - Middle1 and Middle2:

```
public class Main
{
    // All shared properties and methods here
}

public class Middle1 : Main
{
    public void Method1()  
}

public class Middle2 : Main
{
    public void Method2()  
}

public class Sub1 : Middle1
{
    // Don't have access to Method2()  
}

public class Sub2 : Middle2
{
    // Don't have access to Method1()  
}
```

Or define these methods directly in the derived classes:

```
public class Main
{
    // All shared properties and methods here
}

public class Sub1 : Main
{
    public void Method1()  
}

public class Sub2 : Main
{
    public void Method2()  
}
```

Comment: I note that your first sentence is wrong. **Private members are inherited**.  The restriction on private members is that they cannot be *accessed by name* from *outside the declaring class*.  They are certainly inherited!  You can show this easily enough:  `class B
{
 private int x = 123;
 class D : B {
  public D() { Console.WriteLine(this.x); }
 }
}`  class `D` inherits `x` from `B` even though it is private. Since `D` is inside `B` it is allowed to use the name `x`; if `D` were outside `B` then it would not be allowed to use the name, but the field would still be there!

Comment: @EricLippert Of course! a stupid mistake by me. My excuse is lack of sleep. Fixing, thanks! :-)

Comment: To be picky, your edit now has a different error. Not *every* class member is inherited.  Constructors, for instance, are members, but they are not inherited.  And if a class has a destructor, it is not inherited either.

Comment: @EricLippert Please be picky. I find the best way to learn is having to fix your own mistakes.

Comment: Funny, I find the best mistakes to learn from are other people's. :-)